# RDP from Windows to Gnome Desktop on Ubuntu 18.04, Not xfce

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, ubuntu-18.04

So as my question states, I would like to access the gnome desktop of Ubuntu 18.04 from a windows 10 machine. I have this same setup configured on another machine running Ubuntu 16, but I can't seem to replicate what I want to do.

On the first system, I have notes related to what I did in order to enable xrdp access and allow me to remote onto the board. I'll detail what I've done and try to point out differences between the two setups.

The board needs to run headless, so it needs to be able to run the desktop even when an hdmi cable, video, cable is not connected to it. As I will have a GUI auto running once the system boots. It will be running an automated routine, but I may need to log on and access the GUI when I remote onto the desktop. The GUI shows diagnostic data taken while its running.

Please keep in mind, that the following information is all that I have. I'm guessing either I forgot to document something, or the change from 16 to 18 is messing with something.

**Setup 1: Does what I want**

Nvidia TX2

Ubuntu 16 - Jetpack 3.3 r28.2

BSP for Elroy carrier board

Set static IP

sudo apt install x11-xserver-utils

sudo apt install x11vnc

sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-dummy

sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Start x11vnc at startup.
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /homeUSERNAME/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

sudo daemon reload
sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service

Configure headless server

sudo vim /etc/x11/xorg.conf

```
Section "Module"
    Disable     "dri"
    SubSection  "extmod"
        Option  "omit xfree86-dga"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Tegra0"
    Driver      "nvidia"

# Allow X server to be started even if no display devices are connected.
    Option      "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "true"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Default Device"
        Subsection      "Display"
                Depth   24
                Virtual 1680 1024
       EndSubSection
EndSection
```

add RDP support

sudo apt install xrdp
sudo vim /etc /xrdp/xrdp.ini

```
[globals]
bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
port=3389
crypt_level=high
channel_code=1
max_bpp=24
...
...
...

[xrdp1]
name=Remote Desktop
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5900
...
...
...
```

with the above, when I go to remote onto the TX2 with RDP from windows 10, I see this.

[image: XRDP lOGIN]

I log in and see the GNOME desktop like I would if I hooked up a hdmi cable to the board.

**Setup 2 - Does not work**
Nvidia TX2i, ubuntu 18 - jetpack 4.4 and bsp for elroy carrier board.

All the same steps up to
...
...
...

Sudo vim /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

at this point, the xrdp version differs from 0.6.1 to 0.9.5. I attempted to install 0.6.1 with apt installer, but it said that version wasn't available.

If I make no changes to xrdp.ini, when I go to connect with rdp, I get the following options to connect Xorg, X11rdp, Xvnc, console, vnc-any, sesman-any, neutrinordp-any. They all fail to allow me to connect.

I tried to copy over the exact file from the old to the new and it fails to build. So I made just the changes you saw above and it doesn't run as it should.

I ended up adding just the

```
[xrdp1]
name=Remote Desktop
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5900
```

as most of the Global settings are already set.

then I restart xrdp, which I get ===AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE === OK, so I'm assuming its all good.

I attempt to log in, and the first option on the drop box is Remote_Desktop, but when I attempt to log in nothing. It just sits there like this.

[image: XRDP fail]

I again look at the xrdp.ini file to compare, and the differences are the following

***old***______________________________________***new***

bitmap_cache=yes___________________________bitmap_cache=true

bitmap_compression=yes ____________________ bitmap_compression=true

port=3389__________________________________port=3389

crypt_level=high_____________________________crypt_level=high

channel_code=1____________________________Not there at all

max_bpp=24________________________________max_bpp=32

I've updated each of these on the system to match where I can. true I imagine is the same as yes. So i left those, but i updated the max_bpp from 32 to 24, and added channel_code=1, but still nothing.

nothing.

Any insight or help?

Comment: I just use `sudo apt install xrdp` and it works. Are you sure you need all steps mentioned before installing xrdp?

Comment: @Krackout, honestly no I'm not sure. What I do know is that when i attempted to add just xrdp, I would get the XFCE desktop. My boss does not want the XFCE desktop, and has requested the gnome. Keep in mind most of the above, isn't tied directly to remote access. Some of it is configuration for the headless aspect